# Проверка кэша браузера

Tags: браузер, кэширование

Нобходимо проверить кэш браузера, а точнее закеширована ли загружаемая страница или нет. Нужно это для того, чтобы уведомлять пользователей о необходимости очистить кэш в случае, когда на сайте обновился дизайн или т.п. 
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Стандартные механизмы браузера не устраивают?

Comment: 1) Заголовки Last-Modified и If-Modified-Since - поможет только для html-страниц. Для css, js, img можно заморочиться и сделать;

2) Собственно для css, js,  img и прочего - менять в ссылке параметр, например, было '/link/image.jpg?v=1234', должно стать '/link/image.jpg?v=1235'. В итоге такие файлы по умолчанию загрузятся заново.

Просить пользователей что-то сделать самим не есть правильно. Они все равно не сделают.

Comment: Владимир, меня устроят любие решения) просто новичек и не знаю куда копать( Про какие стандартные механизмы вы говорите?

Comment: @uorypm написал уже, могу добавить, что для всяких там картинок можно использовать сборщики gulp/grunt которые будут менять им имена каждый раз при их изменении, чтобы браузер заново их прогрузил.

Comment: Если уж совсем экзотика какая-то (сервер отдает некорректную информацию об изменениях), можете добавить js скрипт, который будет запрашивать версию с сервера, сверять со своей, и выводить нужное сообщение.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо! Буду пробовать)

Comment: @Andrey Думаю надо начать с того, что просто посмотреть а есть ли вообще проблема в данный момент. Т.е. действительно ли при изменении какого то файла на сервере он остается старым на клиенте. По умолчанию web-сервера достаточно правильно настроены и используют механизм last-modified, т.е. браузеры когда страница есть в кеше спрашивают сервер не изменилась ли она.